# Opening URLs in Tasker and get HTTP response and content successfully

Tags: tasker

I am currently doing an automation in Tasker wherein I can open URLs on browser one by one. So far, I have successfully opened URLs by putting the URL list in a text file and have Tasker access it. My problem is, I want to know if each URL has been successfully or better, get the site content? How do I do this? Even if a site has been successfully opened, HTTPR still returns -1. I don't understand why. I also don't know how to use HTTP Get. I'm using Android Emulator by the way. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/how-to-check-success-status-of-opened-url-in-tasker

Answer (score -1):

There's a nice German [tutorial on AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/418890/) ([same page using Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F418890%2F)), explaining this in detail. Moreover, you might want to check with the Q&A [How to check success status of opened URL in Tasker?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21475/how-to-check-success-status-of-opened-url-in-tasker).

Comment: I suppose you must have been a new user when you posted this answer. Would you consider revising it or converting it into a comment? Thanks!

Comment: To prove your assumption, check my profile – and find out you've hit the mark: today - 3y7m makes something around June 2012 :) As for the second part: I've never worked with this, so I prefer to refer to the suggested duplicate :)